# TypeScript can I mix import of regular js in a .ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm using webpack and write in es6.
I'm in the process of integrating typescript to the project.
so my need is to import "old" es6 modules to the new .ts file.
I keep getting the following error:

let's say I have a

```
const consts = {
  login: '/api/login',
  user: '/api/user',
  register: '/api/register'
};

export default consts;
```

and I import this consts to a a.ts file:

```
import * as api from '../consts/api.js';

class A implements {
  constructor() {
    console.log(api)
  }
}

export default AuthorizationServiceDIfa;
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '../consts/api.js'.
```

Comment: do you use a loader ? or the native tsc compiler ?